# How to prevent shitakes from sticking to pan when sauteeing?

Tags: mushrooms, sauteing

Is there any way to prevent shitakes from sticking to the stainless steel pan when sauteeing in olive oil? I cook with many different kinds of mushrooms and only shitakes, and to some degree portobellos, do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use more oil, and fry at a higher temperature. The oil in your picture is not nearly enough to lubricate the sticky parts, and at the low temperature, the mushrooms are producing quite of bit of wet gunk. Also, you should be stirring (or jumping) them a lot, not leaving them to sweat alone.